# Request path is wrong when deployed to github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-actions, github-pages, vite

I want to deploy https://github.com/S-N-O-R-L-A-X/Bridge-Tools to https://s-n-o-r-l-a-x.github.io/Bridge-Tools/.

The deployment seems working well but the page is white. I have searched for some pages and tried as they said but I haven't used router.

By the way, I guess that it is because of the wrong path. Maybe the path should be `https://s-n-o-r-l-a-x.github.io/Bridge-Tools/assets/index-785ed399.css`. However, I don't know where to change it.

package.json is as follows

```
  "homepage": "https://S-N-O-R-L-A-X.github.io/Bridge-Tools",
  "name": "Bridge-Tools",
  "private": false,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear your [`defineConfig`](https://github.com/S-N-O-R-L-A-X/Bridge-Tools/blob/366d98402abbf89ea2700e39a0854ef757e82e34/vite.config.ts#L5-L7) does not set the `base: '/Bridge-Tools/'`, as mentioned in vite's guide for [static sites deployed on GH pages](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages).

For example you should be able to see in the developer tools that at the moment it is experiencing an error in failing to retrieve `https://s-n-o-r-l-a-x.github.io/assets/index-fb37b952.js` and `https://s-n-o-r-l-a-x.github.io/assets/index-785ed399.css`

Comment: Very clear answer and that works, thank you!